# How to Implement SecurityConfig in java spring for jwt token validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

I'm trying to implement Security Config for java spring project for JWT Token validation using spring security 6. Can anyone suggest the steps to implement it using bearer token.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement(management -> management.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        // http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Facing issues to setup configure.

Comment: You can check out this [JWT login sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login) provided by the Spring Security team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to Implement SecurityConfig in java spring for jwt token
> validation

Here are steps to follow:

**1)** Add all necessary dependencies to your project.

**2)** Create a `UserDetailsServiceImpl`  class that implements the `UserDetailsService interface` which is used to load user-specific data during authentication. This class has a method to retrieve the user's details based on the username or any other data passed in the request. It is possible to use any data source  such as a database, a remote service to retrieve the user details.

Here is the code example:

```
import com.zufar.onlinestore.security.repository.UserDetailsRepository;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserDetailsRepository userDetailsRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userDetailsRepository
                .findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User doesn't exists"));
    }
}
```

**3)** Create a `JwtTokenUtil` class. This class is responsible for generating JWT tokens with a secret key and an expiration time, and also for validating JWT tokens passed in the HTTP header of incoming requests.

Here is the code example:

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenUtil {

    private static final String SECRET_KEY = "your-secret-key";
    private static final long EXPIRATION_TIME = 89990000L;

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, SECRET_KEY)
                .compact();
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY).parseClaimsJws(token);
            return true;
        } catch (JwtException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }
}
```

**4)** Create a class that implements `Filter` and extends `OncePerRequestFilter`. This filter is used to validate the JWT token in the incoming requests. This filter works this way:

- The token is retrieved from the header of the HTTP request
- The token is validated.
- If the token is valid, the filter sets the authentication in the `SecurityContextHolder`.

Here is the code example:

```
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;

import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull final HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
                                    @NonNull final HttpServletResponse httpResponse,
                                    @NonNull final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Optional<UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken> authenticationTokenOptional = jwtAuthenticationProvider.get(httpRequest);

        if (authenticationTokenOptional.isPresent()) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = authenticationTokenOptional.get();
            SecurityContextHolder
                    .getContext()
                    .setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);
    }
}
```

**5)** Create a `SpringSecurityConfiguration` class to configure the Spring Security filter chain. This way we can:

- customize the authentication and authorization mechanisms,
- specify the login and logout pages,
- enable/disable CSRF protection,
- and more.

Here is the code example:

```
import com.zufar.onlinestore.security.authentication.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import com.zufar.onlinestore.security.jwt.filter.JwtAuthenticationFilter;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration {
    private static final String API_AUTH_URL_PREFIX = "/api/auth/**";
    public static final String ACTUATOR_ENDPOINTS_URL_PREFIX = "/actuator/**";

    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtTokenFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(API_AUTH_URL_PREFIX).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(ACTUATOR_ENDPOINTS_URL_PREFIX).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity,
                                                       final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                                                       final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailService) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .and()
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Comment: How the JWT token validation is being performed? I don't see any call to validate. Where does JwtAuthenticationProvider comes from?

Comment: in your `JwtTokenUtil` example component where does the `Jwts` object from from?  All of your other examples have imports that one does not.